# MATLAB: Running a function from a previous version

Tags: matlab, least-squares, factorization

### EDIT:

Thank you @yoda and @morispaa. You are both right and @morispaa's solution works, i.e. my processing of the transformed coefficients, which is based on assumptions about the space spanned by **Z**, and the **order** and **"orientation"** of the **Z** vectors, renders the correct result if I update the sign of the columns of **Q** so that the diagonal of **R** has positive elements.

For more details about the transformation I am working on you can read [this](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/digest/2008/jan/zernike.html); **Z** below = sampled Zernike polynomials, which are known for **not** being orthogonal nor complete on the discrete case (our case).

#### Intuition on why the solution proposed by @morispaa works. I would love to hear your input about it:

My intuition is that somehow enforcing **real non-negative diagonals** in **R** renders a basis **Q** that "**aligns**" better with the vectors in **Z** (which, as I said earlier, is non-unitary), and therefore the Options 1 and 2 below, even though they represent different transformations, output coefficients probably in a similar space.

More specifically, I think **Z** is "almost" unitary, and maybe this leads the **QR** decomposition to return a basis that is close enough to **Z**?  Only then I can imagine that my processing of the transformed coefficients, which is based on assumptions about the [specifics](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/digest/2008/jan/zernike.html) of the vectors in **Z**, work when the diagonal of **Q** is fully positive, but not when it has negative entries. What do you think?

### Background

I have both MATLAB **R2011a** and **R2010b** installed on my machine.

One of the changes from **R2010b** to **R2011a** affects the implementation of [`qr()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/qr.html) (see the release notes about this particular change [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/rn/bsq8kw5-1.html#bsvbbib-1)).

An important part of one my projects uses `qr()` to estimate an orthogonal basis for a direct and inverse transformation. My code applies this transformation to an input signal,  processes the transformed coefficients and returns back the processed signal. In other words, the changes made in **R2011a** to `qr()` made the block that process the coefficients of this transformation to stop working (the inverse transformation does not return the expected inverse transformation of the processed signal).

Somehow the **Q** matrix that is now returned from `qr()` is  different from the older version in a way that prevents the processing of the transformed coefficients from working properly.

### First question

In light of the above, is it possible to tell **R2011a** to use `qr()` from **R2010b**?

### Second question

I use **Q** and **Q'** to compute the direct and inverse transformation; you can see more details [**here**](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/digest/2008/jan/zernike.html). More specifically, I use **y = Q * x** and **x = Q' * y** to compute the direct and inverse transformation respectively. A different way to compute the direct transform is using least squares. In other words we have two options:

**Option 1: Direct and inverse transform using QR factorization:**

```
% Direct:
[Q R] = qr(Z);
y = Q' * x;

% Some processing of the y coefficients
% ...

% Inverse:
x = Q*y;
```

**Option 2: Direct and inverse transform via least squares fitting**

```
% Direct:
y = Z \ x;

% Some processing of the y coefficients
% ...

% Inverse:
x = Z*y;
```

where our variables are:

```
% x = Input vector
% y = Direct transformation of x
% Z = Matrix with sampled basis
```

In **R2011a** the Option 1 above **stopped working** (it works in **R2010b**). I really like the idea of using `qr()` for the direct and inverse transform (it's much faster than computing least-squares for every new vector). If I wanted to use the new `qr()` for my project, does anybody know how to make my transformation work again with the new **Q**?

Comment: In what way does the output from the "new" `qr()` differ?  Is it completely broken?  Or is it simply tiny numerical discrepancies that could be attributed to standard floating-point issues?  It it's the latter, if your entire application is breaking, it's probably a sign that your algorithm is not numerically stable.  (I appreciate that this is not a very helpful response to your question...)

Comment: Thanks @Oli. I am highly confident this is not a numerical stability problem, and more a problem related to the differences between the **Q** matrices returned by the new and old version (I think the `QR` factorization is not unique). The new `qr()` is probably correct, but the new factorization does not satisfy the same properties that the old one did. I think the problem comes from the non-negativity of the diagonal of the **R** matrix, a property that was guaranteed in the previous version, but not in the new one, and that somehow affects the matrix **Q** as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a **QR** factorization as `A=QR`, `R` is an upper-triangular matrix. If your matrix `A` is *invertible*, then the factorization is *unique* if you impose the condition that `R` has real, non-negative diagonals. If this condition is relaxed, you get an orthogonal matrix `Q` and an upper-triangular matrix `R`, but they needn't be unique.

The non-uniqueness of decompositions often confuses people, and I thought I'd point you to one of my favorite examples: [*the eigenvectors of an identity matrix*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648975/matlab-vs-mathematica-eigenvectors/5652184#5652184).

From the link you provided:

> **Compatibility Considerations:**
>    Since the
>   QR factorization is not unique, these
>   different results are still correct.
>   Ensure that your code does not depend
>   on the values of the elements of the
>   factors Q and R.

Is this what's happening with your code? Does it depend on the form of `Q` and `R`?

As a quick fix, could you try this from `R2010b`:

`which qr.m`

On my machine, I get `/Applications/MATLAB_R2010b.app/toolbox/matlab/matfun/qr.m`. Could you try copying this function and putting it in your `R2011` path, and rename it as `qr2010` or something? Then whenever you need the old function, you can call `qr2010` from the latest version of MATLAB and it should use the old algorithm. I haven't tested this, so let me know if it works.

**EDIT**

I installed `R2011a` on my machine and checked out `qr`. Like I said, not enforcing the positive diagonals will result in different combinations for the signs of the elements, thereby rendering the solution non-unique. However, the forward and inverse transformations should work and it does so on my machine.

```
A=magic(5);x=(1:5)';   %'
[Q R]=qr(A);
y=Q'*x;                %'
z=Q*y;

z'

ans =

    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000
```

I get the same result in both `R2011a` and `R2010b`. So, my guess is somehow you're relying on the diagonals being positive, which is probably not a good thing to do.

But if you want to retain your code, but instead get the new `qr` to return the same matrices as in `R2010b`, then you should use morispaa's suggestion.

**EDIT 2**

Explanation of morispaa's solution: Since in `2010b`, the diagonals of `R` are positive to get the same behavior in `2011a`, all you need to do is get the sign of the diagonals and propagate it throughout the `R` matrix. For my example above, `R` is

```
R =

  -32.4808  -26.6311  -21.3973  -23.7063  -25.8615
         0   19.8943   12.3234    1.9439    4.0856
         0         0  -24.3985  -11.6316   -3.7415
         0         0         0  -20.0982   -9.9739
         0         0         0         0  -16.0005
```

and `D` is

```
D =

    -1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0    -1     0     0
     0     0     0    -1     0
     0     0     0     0    -1
```

The diagonals of `R` automatically become positive (it's as simple as `-1*-1=1`). Similarly, you propagate the sign in the `Q` matrix. Note that `D*D` is simply the square of the elements for a diagonal matrix, and is equal to `I`, the identity matrix. Hence, we get

```
 Q2*R2=Q*D*D*R
      =Q*I*R
      =Q*R
      =A
```

Comment: Thank you @yoda, you are right. This is very helpful and @morispaa's solution works, although I don't know why. I updated the question to reflect all this!

Comment: Thank you @yoda, If it's not too much to ask, I would be curious to know what you think about the intuition I gave in the EDIT section of my post about why the processing of the transformed coefficients works when **D** has only positive entries work, but **not** when it includes negative entries.

Comment: @AmV: I too don't know anything about Zernike polynomials. However, I don't think it has anything to do with the diagonals of `Q`. You'll find that its diagonals can have negative entries (maybe not for your example) even in `R2010b`. The constraint is only on the diagonals of `R`, not `Q`.

Answer (score 2):

I think (don't have MATLAB at hand at the moment) that you can restore the behavior of the version 2010b as follows:

```
[Q R] = qr(Z);
D = diag(sign(diag(R)));
R2 = D*R;
Q2 = Q*D;
```

Now `R2` will be upper triagonal, have positive diagonal, `Q2` stays orthogonal (or unitary) and `Q2*R2 = Z`. In complex case use

```
R2 = D'*R;
Q2 = Q*D;
```

Comment: Thank you @morispaa. This is very helpful and answers my second question! I still don't understand why though, I updated the question in the **EDIT** section at the top to reflect this.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about Zernike polynomials, but could it be that using QR decomposition that does not force non-negative diagonal in R somehow messes up the handedness of the orthogonal basis that the row vectors of Q span? Just a guess...